# Варианты пунктуации после "Главное"

Tags: пунктуация

Главное не оценивать себя.

Как я понимаю, в этом предложении после "главное" возможна как запятая, так и тире. Верно?

Можно ли вообще обойтись безо всякого пунктуационного знака, если главное — подлежащее?

Comment: Без знаков не получится - нельзя подобрать правило, Ное если вы хотите получить обоснованный ответ при выборе знака,  то добавьте контекст. Без него высказывание не представляется ясным.

Answer (score 2):

1) Для меня ставить знаки препинания без контекста – сложно, поэтому при его отсутствии я придумываю текст сама.
Например:

*Полюбите себя – это позволит вам жить в согласии с собой.  Примите себя таким, какой вы есть. **ГлАвное – не оцЕнивать себя**. Перестаньте сравнивать себя с кем бы то ни было.*

Теперь я вижу расстановку ударений, поэтому *главное* – подлежащее, а инфинитив – сказуемое. В таких случаях ставится тире.

2) **Вариант с  обособлением запятой вводного слова не подходит.** Он выглядит примерно так: *Только не волнуйся. **Главное**, не расходовать нЕрвы! **Главное**, не терять незавИсимости.* Это безличные инфинитивные предложения. Вводное слово интонационно не выделяется.

3) **Можно ли обособить вводное слово тире?** Вот примеры:  *К этому стону они особенно  долго прислушивались, стараясь  не спутать его с другими звуками ночи, **а главное** ― не упустить его…*

***Главное*** ― не вижу, на чём же тут работать. Столы да стены!

4) **Можно ли вообще не ставить знака?** Вот пример:

*Вот видите, как криво получается? Потому что я сейчас думаю не о том, что пишу, а о том, что сейчас начнется служба, **и мне главное не опоздАть**. Каллиграфия требует определенного настроения.*

Comment: Согласен с ответом, за исключением невозможности "вводного" контекста. Вообразим беседу с психотерапевтом. "Что можно посоветовать в таком случае? Главное, не оценивать себЯ. Затем, перестать сравнивать себЯ с другИми" и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно Розенталю, "Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или **если один из главных членов выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — неопределенной формой глагола**"

В данном случае "главное" - субстантивированное прилагательное в роли существительного. То есть, если вы расцениваете "Главное" как подлежащее, надо ставить тире.

Но "Главное" может быть и вводным словом, тогда вместо тире нужна запятая:

```
Главное, надо теперь поужинать и отдохнуть. *И. Тургенев, Отцы и дети.*
```

Comment: Скажите, а частица НЕ влияет на выбор знака? И если "главное"  - это вводное слово, то можно поставить тире?  И как тогда отличить подлежащее от вводного слова? И еще, извините, вопрос: выбор знака зависит от контекста или нет?

Comment: Розенталь о каких-либо исключениях, связанных с отрицанием, не упоминает. Есть примеры и в литературе: «Главное ― не надо думать», ― твердил он самому себе. (Тургенев, Отцы и дети)

Comment: Вводные слова тире никогдя не отделяют! А отличить в данном случае сложно. Но вообще-то, когда после слова "главное" - инфинитив, и это явно сказуемое, то "главное" почти точно подлежащее, потому что из одного сказуемого-инфинитива предложение уж очень неполное.

Comment: Дополню. Я не совсем точно ответил, вводное слово можно отличить: его возможно убрать без кардинального ущерба для смысла. Сравните: "Главное - верить в себя" и "Главное, верить в себя нужно".

Comment: Частица "не" влияет на тире, если сказуемое не инфинитив (мета: как в этом предложении).

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

При изъятии слова "*главное*" нарушается смысл — предложение "*не оценивать себя*" корректным не представляется. Следовательно, это подлежащее и нужно тире:
*ГлАвное — не оценивать себя.* || Ударение падает на первое слово.

А вот "*надо не оценивать себя*", как у Тургенева, уже может существовать отдельно. Тогда "*главное*" — вводное слово:
*Главное, надо не оценивать себя.*
или
*Главное, не надо оценивать себя.*

Без знаков это слово что-то не используют.